# Unexpected behavior when using Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have this code:

```
// positions is a List<Position>
Parallel.ForEach(positions, (position) =>
{
    DeterminePostPieceIsVisited(position, postPieces);
});

private void DeterminePostPieceIsVisited(Position position, IEnumerable<Postpieces> postPieces)
{
    foreach (var postPiece in postPieces)
    {
        if (postPiece.Deliverd)
            continue;

            var distanceToClosestPosition = postPiece.GPS.Distance(position.GPS);

            postPiece.Deliverd = distanceToClosestPosition.HasValue && IsInRadius(distanceToClosestPosition.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that 50 post pieces must have the property `Deliverd` set to true. But, when running this code, I get changing results. Sometimes I get 44, when I run it another time I get 47. The results are per execution different.

When I run this code using a plain foreach-loop I get the expected result. So I know my implementation of the method `DeterminePostPieceIsVisited` is correct.

Could someone explain to me why using the Parallel foreach gives me different results each time I execute this code?

Comment: You are asking all the parallel workers to iterate over the *same* `postPieces` collection. Having mltiple writers to a non-thread-safe object is asking for trouble.

Comment: What would be a solution to solve this?

Comment: Why are you using `Parallel.ForEach` in such a case ?

Comment: I want to learn to use it and I want to measure it's performance.

Comment: Your iteration's work is just so simple that you don't need to use a parallel foreach. You need to test it when the iteration's work is a long-running work.

Comment: I know, but I still would like to know how to solve this. Imagine that this work is heavy, in such a situation I would like to know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

You've already, I think, tried to avoid a race, but there is still one - if two threads are examining the same `postPiece` at the same time, they may *both* observe that `Deliverd` (sic) is `false`, and then both assess whether it's been delivered to `position` (a distinct value for each thread) and both attempt to set a value for `Deliverd` - and often, I would guess, one of them will be trying to set it to `false`. Simple fix:

```
private void DeterminePostPieceIsVisited(Position position, IEnumerable<Postpieces> postPieces)
{
    foreach (var postPiece in postPieces)
    {
        if (postPiece.Deliverd)
            continue;

        var distanceToClosestPosition = postPiece.GPS.Distance(position.GPS);

        var delivered = distanceToClosestPosition.HasValue && IsInRadius(distanceToClosestPosition.Value);
        if(delivered)
            postPiece.Deliverd = true;
    }
}
```

Also, by the way:

> When I run this code using a plain foreach-loop I get the expected result. So I know my implementation of the method `DeterminePostPieceIsVisited` is correct.

The correct thing to state is would be "I know my implementation is correct *for single threaded access*" - what you hadn't established is that the method was safe for calling from multiple threads.

Comment: Good solution, only thing worries me is more than one thread writing on same memory location, which cannot be avoided in this case either, though this will surely not lead to race condition, data corruption and avoid lock too but if load is high will it cause memory corruption, may be some sort of Access Violation

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - there's no memory corruption issue here that I can see, so long as `Deliverd` is a field or a trivial setter of a field. Writes to `bool`s are [atomic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever How can that be guaranteed for the code `postPiece.Deliverd = true;`, which is allocated and modified on the heap

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - I'm not sure what you're thinking of here. From the code we have available to us in the question, we have *zero* knowledge of where anything is allocated, nor is it clear why you think where something is allocated has any effect over the fact that in C#, it's guaranteed that writes to `bool`s are in fact atomic.

Comment: Let me rephrase, do you think if there's global boolean value, and its modified by multiple threads, would there be a scope of race condition, which can corrupt the data or there's no need of thread safety, since it will always be an atomic operation.

In my understanding, the solution that you have provide, still cannot prevent more than one thread writing the same memory location and if it has to be atomic then there will be no need for thread safety for modification of value type like boolean, which is not the case.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - no, there is **no** scope for corruption here. Threads may compete to write to this location - but you'll only ever find either `true` or `false` stored here (due to atomicity guarantees). And, given the assumed scope of the problem here (and given my suggested change) we only ever have a) no threads attempting updates or b), multiple threads attempting to store `true`.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever Alright thanks, regarding the solution provided, I am aware it would prevent the data corruption that OP is facing, as only option threads passing the if loop is to write the true value

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue with `ConcurrentBag<T>`. Here's what I use now:

```
var concurrentPostPiecesList = new ConcurrentBag<Postpiece>(postPieces);
Parallel.ForEach(positions, (position) => 
{
    DeterminePostPieceIsVisited(position, concurrentPostPiecesList);
});

private void DeterminePostPieceIsVisited(Position position, ConcurrentBag<Postpieces> postPieces)
{
    foreach (var postPiece in postPieces)
    {
        if (postPiece.Deliverd)
            continue;

        var distanceToClosestPosition = postPiece.GPS.Distance(position.GPS);

        postPiece.Deliverd = distanceToClosestPosition.HasValue && IsInRadius(distanceToClosestPosition.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have used the solution with Thread safety, as I have suggested, just a thread safe data structure. Difficult for me to suggest this answer, since not aware of source of IEnumerable and whether you need Ordering / Indexing, which are not possible in a ConcurrentBag